# How to define a file/page using conditional comments?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am curious as to how to utilize conditional comments to define pages/files with PHP.

This technique is used in WordPress; one can define the template file by inserting conditional comments at the top of the file. Then when you select this template, the application knows which file to use. Something like this;

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Snarfer
*/
?>
```

I would like to point out that I do not wish to perform this actin in a WordPress environment, but I am curious as to how they do it.

So how can one use this technique in PHP? I would assume one needs to create a function or a class or a series of functions and classes.

I have tried searching but perhaps I'm using the wrong keywords in my search.

If anybody could point me to documentation or tutorials i would be very appreciative.

Comment: WP reads up all php scripts once, extracts those comment meta infos, and keeps a separate list.

Comment: @mario thanks for that, I have just refined my search terms a bit further based on your comment and come up with two possibilities to do this; 1) the ReflectionClass with getDocComment or 2) token_get_all. Thanks for the push, I'm going to research these two and see how it goes. Cheers

Comment: WP uses a very simple technique for this I believe, maybe a regex. It's all in the WordPress source code should you wish to see it for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

I think you must have to give the condition on wordpress archive.php to check which custom post type you like to use and you can define here to which templete file you like to call.

```
<?php if ( 'news' == get_post_type() ) { ?>

            <div class="container">

                    <?php
                        /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'news-blog', get_post_format() ); 
                    ?>

            </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
Wordpress Default call
<?php } ?>
```

in `get_template_part( 'news-blog', get_post_format() );`  having news-blog is the file name of you template. for example news-blog.php